# Is this statement about Abelian/Tauberian theorems true?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, power-series

Suppose we have some real constants $c_n \geq 0$, and know that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_nr^n$$ converges for all $r \in (0,1)$. Suppose that the limit

$$\lim_{r \uparrow 1} (1-r)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n r^n $$

exists (and is finite). Can we deduce that $c:= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} c_n $ exists, and that

$$c = \lim_{r \uparrow 1} (1-r)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n r^n  \quad ?$$

If not, are there some extra conditions on $c_n$ that makes this true?

Many thanks for your help

Comment: If $\sum_{n\to \infty}c_n$ exists, for example let $c_n=0.5^n$, $\lim_{r\to1-0}(1-r)\sum c_n r^n=\lim_{r\to1-0}(1-r)\times Constant=0$?